# A service will always receive the Broadcast Action that registered for?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have created a service which is supposed to receive the `android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED/ACL_CONNECTED` events.

I am aware that services in android may be restarted/stopped when android decides.

However, I am wondering whether a service is always guaranteed to receive the events it registered for, even it has been killed by android?

I assume this means that android will need to restart a killed service which has registered to listen to events when that event takes place.
Is the above assumption correct ?

---

Thank you very much for the quick reply.

Let me give some more information, sample of the code follows:

```
public class my_service extends Service {

    @Override     
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {   
        ...   
        IntentFilter filterDisconnected = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiverDisconnected, filterDisconnected);  
        ...
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiverDisconnected = new BroadcastReceiver() {  

        @Override  
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
            ...  
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

So with this code the BroadcastReceiver is implemented within the service class.

This code is working fine under normal cirmustances but are you saying that this is not proper and a different class (BroadcastReceiver ) is needed ?

If the above is proper, i  am wondering if this service class is stopped for any reason, when the relevant event is raised,  the class will be restarted and the BroadcastReceiver will get the event.

Comment: You created a new unregistered account (I've merged it into this one) please consider registering so this won't happen again.  Also, answers are for answers, not updates.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> Hi all, i have created a service which is supposed to receive the android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED/ACL_CONNECTED events.

That should not be possible. Those are documented as being broadcast actions; if true, then they can only be picked up by a `BroadcastReceiver`.

> However, i am wondering whether a service is always guaranteed to receive the events it registered for, even it has been killed by android ?

Again, services should never "receive" those events directly.

However, if you create a `BroadcastReceiver` and put it in the manifest with an `<intent-filter>` for your desired broadcasts, then that `BroadcastReceiver` is "guaranteed to receive the events it registered for", and that `BroadcastReceiver` can call `startService()` to send a command to an `IntentService` if desired.